# Apache Camel Timer Nullpointer exception at Fat Jar

Tags: java, gradle, timer, apache-camel

I'm trying to implement a timer using Camel 3.5 at Gradle project with OpenJDK8 as next

```
     from("timer://watchexpiration?fixedRate=true&period=600000&delay=0")...
```

But, after build the fat jar using `./gradlew build` and run as `java -jar build/libs/app.jar`

I receive the next error at console

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: timer://watchexpiration?delay=0&fixedRate=true&period=600000 due to: Error binding property (delay=0) with name: delay on bean: timer://watchexpiration?delay=0&fixedRate=true&period=600000 with value: 0
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doGetEndpoint(AbstractCamelContext.java:888)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.getEndpoint(AbstractCamelContext.java:777)
    at org.apache.camel.support.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:58)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.AbstractReifier.resolveEndpoint(AbstractReifier.java:177)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.doCreateRoute(RouteReifier.java:250)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.createRoute(RouteReifier.java:112)
```

But If I run using `./gradlew run` then **works fine** as I expected.
I don't want to use any frameworks for this project. I feel this is just a config issue or something is wrong with my configuration I guess.

How can I fix it?

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'com.github.sherter.google-java-format' version '0.8'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.2'
    // Camel
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-core', version: '3.5.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-file', version: '3.5.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-file-watch', version: '3.5.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-xstream', version: '3.5.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-gson', version: '3.5.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-rest', version: '3.5.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-servlet', version: '3.5.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-http', version: '3.5.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-jackson', version: '3.5.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-quartz', version: '3.5.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-timer', version: '3.5.0'

    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.7.30'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.30'

    // Dev Libs
    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12")

    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-csv', version: '1.4'
}

application {
    mainClassName = 'com.eip.App'
}

configurations {
    // configuration that holds jars to include in the jar
    extraLibs
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'com.beam.agent.App'
        )
    }
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

googleJavaFormat {
    exclude '**/App.java'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shadowing jars can be tricky, because you need to handle duplicate entries. In Apache Camel there are many `META-INF` service files, which are getting overwritten with your simple `jar` approach. Use [`com.github.johnrengelman.shadow`](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/) which is allowing you to customize the merging process.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'com.github.sherter.google-java-format' version '0.8'
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "6.0.0" // Added plugin
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    // ...
}
application {
    mainClassName = 'com.eip.App'
}
// Removed jar step
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
googleJavaFormat {
    exclude '**/App.java'
}
// Added shadow plugin configuration
shadowJar {
    mergeServiceFiles() // Tell plugin to merge duplicate service files
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.eip.App'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
```

Shaded executable jar will have suffix `-all.jar`

```
java -jar build/libs/app-all.jar
```

Comment: Thanks for your quickly answer. Sorry for the Jira ticket. Works fine! Thanks again!